# How do I setup Rails for deployment on my Ubuntu14.04 system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I've recently been working on an app, and decided to switch from PHP and use Ruby on Rails instead. I then followed a tutorial on how to install Rails on Ubuntu 14.04, and after completion of the the tutorial I was left with a question, how in the heck do I run my Rails application? In previous tutorials I was told to use the `rails server` command to do this task. After I ran the command I went to my URL and saw no sign of my rails server working. I then shut the rails server down and pointed my sites port 80 to the directory in which my rails app was held. Still with no success I am seeking counsel from the internet.

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: When you run `rails server`, what appears on your command line?

Comment: I think I see something, It's starting the server on localhost not my IP,. Anyway, => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-05-26 21:48:49] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-05-26 21:48:49] INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-05-26 21:48:49] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=13508 port=3000

Comment: So if this is the problem how do I get it to run on my IP instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append `-b` followed by desired IP and then `-p` followed by your desired port.